# Splicing an entire column in dataframe based on find function criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df Hubspot where

```
df['Email Domain'][1] = google.com
```

all other rows are basically different website names.

I want to extract the name of the website (eg. google in the case above)
This lets me does that for one row:

```
df['Email Domain'][1][0:df['Email Domain'][1].find('.')]
```

What generic function would do that for the entire column in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and index on the first item:

```
df['Email Domain'].str.split('.').str[0]
```